# How to ask for more buffer from source in gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I am writing a gstreamer sink based on gstbasesink that will wrap an fpga playing video through an NTSC video encoder. I have my own driver that sends request (basically, vsync signal) for frame data via irq. With gstreamer plugin sink acting as user application, it polls for frame data request via ioctl.

The vsync is fixed at 30fps, and the data needed is interlaced data with 480x720 size, YUY2.

The source I am using is videotestsrc running at 60fps progressive.

I am a total beginner in gstreamer, what I want to do is to get 2 buffers in between vsync, and interlace it inside render() method. and send one full frame to the device.

I am at loss with how to "ask" the source for 2 buffers in one vsync.

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling you're doing more work than you need to, but maybe create a custom `appsink` and use `gst_app_sink_pull_sample`?

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-appsink.html

Comment: If I am outputting 30fps interlaced, shouldn't I need 60fps progressive to properly show 1 frame? isn't one interlaced frame comprise of 240-line even field, and 240-line odd field sampled at different time?

Comment: I was going to implement pull-mode sink for this, using queue2 element, I read somewhere that it can provide a pull-mode src pad. e.g. `videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=720,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! queue2 ! appsink`. However, I can't seem to figure out why basesink never activates as pull-mode even though I have implemented the necessary function, and set `can-activate-pull` to TRUE

Comment: I think it's more like if you receive 30fps interlaced, you'll run it through a deinterlacer and output 30fps progressive (or maybe you have a TV or something that is designed to be displayed in interlaced mode so no deinterlacing will occur), it'll just be lower quality and use less bandwidth.